# Map list to bin numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Does WL have the equivalent of [Matlab's discretize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.discretize.html) or [NumPy's digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)?  I.e., a function that takes a length-N list and a list of bin edges and returns a length-N list of bin numbers, mapping each list item to its bin number?

Comment: [`HistogramList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) seems similar. This could also be done efficiently with `GroupBy` and some easy little `Compile`-d selection determiner. Or maybe hit it first with `Sort` then write something that only checks the next bin up. Again, can be easily `Compile`-d.

Comment: I need it to work like a map (in terms of the order of the items in the resulting list).  Of course it is possible to write something ...

Comment: Related: [140577](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140577/45431)

Comment: Did you try `BinCounts`?  I guess it is what you need.

Comment: @Rom38 You probably meant `BinLists`, right?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, they both do the similar things. `BinCount` can form the list of bins according to the submitted list of ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version based on [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest):

```
digitize[edges_] := DigitizeFunction[edges, Nearest[edges -> "Index"]]
digitize[data_, edges_] := digitize[edges][data]

DigitizeFunction[edges_, nf_NearestFunction][data_] := With[{init = nf[data][[All, 1]]},
    init + UnitStep[data - edges[[init]]] - 1
]
```

For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[10, 10]
digitize[data, {2, 4, 5, 7, 8}]
```

> {8.17389, 1.1142, 7.89526, 1.87803, 2.41361, 0.657388, 5.42247, 2.31155, 3.96006, 7.00474}
>
> {5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 4}

Note that I broke up the definition of `digitize` into two pieces, so that if you do this for multiple data sets with the same `edges` list, you only need to compute the nearest function once.

Answer (score 6):

This is a *very* quick-n-dirty, but may serve as a simple example.

This creates a *piecewise function* following the first definition in *Matlab's discretize* documentation, then applies that to the data.

```
disc[data_, edges_] := Module[{e = Partition[edges, 2, 1], p, l},
   l = Length@e;
   p=Piecewise[Append[Table[{i, e[[i, 1]] <= x < e[[i, 2]]}, {i, l - 1}]
                          , {l,e[[l, 1]] <= x <= e[[l, 2]]}]
                   , "NaN"];
   Table[p, {x, data}]];
```

From the first example in the above referenced documentation:

```
data={1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8, 10, 4, 4};
edges={2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

disc[data,edges]
```

> {NaN,NaN,1,1,3,2,4,4,2,2}

I'm sure there are more efficient/elegant solutions, and will revisit as time permits.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use `Interpolation` with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`. However, employing `Nearest` as Carl Woll did will usually be much faster.

First, we prepare the interplating function.

```
m = 20;
binboundaries = Join[{-1.}, Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m - 1]], {1.}];

f = Interpolation[Transpose[{binboundaries, Range[0, m]}], InterpolationOrder -> 0];
```

Now you can apply it to lists of values as follows:

```
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000];   
Round[f[vals]]
```